# Getting Bluetooth MAC Address on Android from native application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing a native C application for Android 6.0. As part of the requirement of the application, I would have to get the Bluetooth MAC Address of the device. Can I please know how do I get it ( Like any API from Bluedroid with which I can call from my native C Application to get the MAC Address. Everywhere I get an Java Application where in they use the API.

Note: 
I am new to Android / Bluedroid hence Kindly elaborate the answer.

Comment: since android 6 the request to get the bluetooth mac address returns a constant value. You cannot use it anymore

Comment: @TimCastelijns but how is the Settings/About/Status/Bluetooth able to show a MAC Address ?